# Find and replace across text runs in MS Word XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, openxml

I have been trying to find and replace across XML text runs using the Python LXML library. My current attempt:

```
v = ''
position = -1
positions = []

for cur in root.iter('t'):
    v = v + cur.text
    position = position + len(cur.text)
    positions.append(position)

v = v.replace("test string", "this is a test string")

i = 0
start = 0
end = positions[0]

for cur in root.iter('t'):
    try:
        cur.text = v[start:end]
        print cur.text
        start = end
        i = i + 1
        end = positions[i]
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Simplified Example XML:

```
<t>this is a test</t>
<w>asdfasdfsadf</w>
<t>test<t>
<w>ajsdfkladkjsf</w>
<t> string</t>
```

This approach puts the contents of the  tags into a string, and keeps track of the indices where the split occurs. It then does the replacements on the string and writes the string back into the XML at roughly the same position. Unfortunately, once I open the file in Word there are random spaces missing and added elsewhere. I know that this method will probably not work, but what is the best way to go about solving this problem with the lxml parser.

EDIT: I do not want to read the file in as a string and edit it, I want to edit the file and keep all the formatting.

Comment: if its same string and has to be replaced in whole doc - you don't care that its xml - just read all file for line in file replace if string_to_replace in line

Comment: If I read the file in won't it still be xml splitting up the string?

Comment: you read file line by line: with open(file, 'r') as f: for line in f ....

Comment: Why don't you just call replace on each `t.text`?

Comment: The t.text are often split up.